# How can I make albert adopt the widget theme of my system?

Tags: albert

On my Gnome desktop Albert widgets look like this although I use the ArcDark theme:

[image]

How can I make albert adopt the GTK theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most distributions configure their desktops to have uniform look and feel over the toolkits. However some do not (e.g. Arch) and users have to configure it on their own. The Arch Linux wiki has a good [article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications) on this topic. In my personal experience (on arch) setting the following environment variable: `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2` yielded the best results. Note that the gtk+ qt style has been removed from `qt-base`, but ist still available in the [qtstyleplugins](https://github.com/qt/qtstyleplugins) package (On Arch [`qt5-styleplugins`<sup>AUR</sup>](https://github.com/qt/qtstyleplugins)). Put the env var above into `/etc/environment` and the widgets (of all Qt apps btw) should look like this:

[image]